# Category Slug Still Exist After Changed in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, categories, slug

The only thing I did, is changed the Slug under the WooCommerce Product Category. Category Slug ***From***: `/box/` ***change to*** `/best-box/`

After Changing the Slug:

- `example.com/box/` - ***404 error***
- `example.com/box/wooden-box/` - ***404 error***
- `example.com/best-box/` - ***OK***
- `example.com/best-box/wooden-box/` ***OK***

However, if I enter the exact ***product URL*** under this category:

- `example.com/box/wooden-box/DF300-box` - ***OK***
- `example.com/best-box/wooden-box/DF300-box` - ***OK***

Shouldn't the ***product URL*** with `/box/` be **404 error** as well? If I don't solve this, then google is telling me these 2 URLs are having the same Title, Meta Description, and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***redirect 301 plugins***:

Redirect from: `example.com/box/wooden-box/DF300-box`

To: `example.com/best-box/wooden-box/DF300-box`